Can I use Xcode to code for the VEX V5 Brain with PROS (3.8.0)?
I'm currently working with the VEX V5 Brain and want to use Xcode for development with PROS (version 3.8.0) because I prefer native operation (I use a Mac). From my research, it seems like most of the documentation and community discussions around PROS and VEX robotics development suggest using Python and the terminal/command line tools. However, I'm specifically interested in integrating PROS with Xcode, as I'm more comfortable with that environment.
What I've Tried:

I reviewed the PROS documentation and it mentions using a Linux-based toolchain with Python. Most of the tutorials and guides I've come across focus on setting up PROS with a command-line interface (CLI), not with IDEs like Xcode.

I also explored the PROS GitHub repositories, but I couldn't find any references to supporting Xcode or integrating PROS directly with it.

I thought about downloading PROS and installing it as a library or repository in Xcode, but I couldn't find any instructions on how to do this either. The instructions I encountered mostly involve using Python and a terminal-based workflow.

In terms of hardware, I have the VEX V5 Brain connected via USB, and I am comfortable using VEXcode to upload programs. But I want to move away from VSCode and use PROS with Xcode if possible.


My Question:
Is it possible to use Xcode to develop with PROS for the VEX V5 Brain? If so, how would I go about setting it up? Alternatively, is there a way to configure Xcode as a suitable IDE for PROS development, or would I have to rely on a terminal-based workflow for this version of PROS (3.8.0)?
Any guidance on how to integrate PROS with Xcode, or if it's feasible at all, would be greatly appreciated.

Extremely simplified, Xcode (and any other possible IDE) is really nothing more than a glorified text editor. If the language you want to program is using text-files, then it can be edited in Xcode. There won't be any of the usual help you get with a language like C++, like for example syntax highlighting or tips as you code, but it is definitely possible to edit any text-file.

You actually want to use xcode ? More seriously xcode isn't a very extensible IDE, if you want to do anything outside what apple supports, you can use it as a text editor but it won't do anything else
